# Disable checking for specific JavaScript error in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

I'm trying to use Eclipse for JavaScript (the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" package).

My project uses Bluebird (a promises implementation), and so it has a lot of lines like:

```
somePromise.catch(function(err){...
```

Eclipse considers this to be an error, probably because it thinks that "catch" is a reserved keyword that cannot be used as a method name. Same for the promise.finaly method. Maybe it's right, but I'd rather not switch to a different library just because of this.

Is there a way to make it ignore these specific errors (but keep reporting other errors in the same files)?

Comment: Reported as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457830

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but Eclipse's Problems tab can be filtered. If you click the little upside down triangle and select "Configure Contents..." you may be able to create a filter so that the errors you report don't show there.

Comment: My work-around (until Eclipse bug is fixed) is to use somePromise["catch"](function(err){...  Ugly, but for me it looked better than seeing a prominent but spurious error.

Comment: doesn't eclipse have some sort of support for `jshint` overrides from the default linter?

Comment: Dude, mark response as the correct answer - it works!

Answer (score 7):

This has been reported and fixed not long ago in this bug :https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443876

Go into Preferences->Javascript->Validator->Errors/Warnings and uncheck a new option "Strict validation of JavaScript keywords usage". That should fix it.

I had the same problem before and had implemented a plugin that manipulated bytecode of JSDT at load time to silence this error. Now such hacks are not needed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me :(
I am on **Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)**

Comment: I'm on the same version and can confirm it still works. Make sure you rebuild the project in question.

Comment: Ah! worked for **of** but still complains for **delete** keyword

Comment: If you are willing to try Eclipse Neon, there is an [alpha of a revamped JSDT](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/alpha-for-neon.html) available. That one supports ES5 and ES6 syntax.

Comment: Always game for new stuff.. let me give it a try